# How do I keep section numbering isolated when including standalone files?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, standalone

Suppose I have a file `test2.tex` which includes the contents of another file, `test1.tex`.

Both of these files are standalone documents (ie. I want to be able to compile `test.tex` on its own).

`test1.tex` has the following content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section X}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, it produces

> 1 Section X

`test2.tex` has the following content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\input{test1}
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, it produces:

> 1 Section 1
>
> 2 Section X
>
> 3 Section 2

But what I *want* is:

> 1 Section 1
>
> 1 Section X
>
> 2 Section 2

How do I confine the included file to its own "environment" (I don't know what this is called in latex - I'm just learning). Just to reiterate, I want to make sure that `test1.tex` remains a compilable file in its own right, and I'd prefer not to modify it if possible.

Comment: Is there any feedback on this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am away from my desk until Monday but I'll be sure to respond as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `standalone` does not preserve counter values, it just `glues` the documents together (with some precautions of course due to packages,`\begin{document}...\end{document}` etc.)

A special environment would not help here, since `LaTeX` counters are not group safe.

The package `xassoccnt` provides the `\BackupCounterValues{section,...}` command,that stores the values of the counters given in the list and resets the counters. Afterwards use `\RestoreAllCounterValues` to restore the values.

(I am the author of `xassoccnt` and I want to provide 'backup' lists, i.e. predefined list of counters, that can be handed over to the `\BackupCounterValues` macro. In the current version, this is not possible yet)

`test1.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section X}
\end{document}
```

Driver file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\BackupCounterValues{section,figure,table} % and perhaps other counters
\input{test1}
\RestoreAllCounterValues
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]